# Why am I getting "Invalid JSON string" from Advanced Calendar Service?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm attempting to call the Advanced Calendar Service from a Google Apps Script as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar).  I have setup what I think is a pretty straightforward call:

```
  // Retrieve busy info from Calendar API
  var events = Calendar.Freebusy.query({
    timeMin: startDateTime.toISOString(),
    timeMax: endDateTime.toISOString(),
    items: [
      {id: "<Calendar Id>"},
      {id: "<Another Calendar Id>"}
    ]
  });
  var len = events.length;
  Logger.log(len);
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Logger.log(events[i].getTitle());
  }
```

(Obviously, I have real calendar id's in my version of the code.)

However, when I run the above code, I get an error on the very first line.  The Execution transcript shows the following error message:

```
[14-07-28 12:41:05:640 EDT] Execution failed: Invalid JSON string: {
 "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
 "timeMin": "2014-07-28T14:30:00.000Z",
 "timeMax": "2014-08-01T20:00:00.000Z",
 "calendars": {
  "<Calendar Id>": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2014-07-28T20:00:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-28T21:00:00Z"
    }
   ]
  },
  "<Another Calendar Id>": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2014-07-28T17:00:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-28T17:30:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2014-07-28T18:00:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-28T20:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2014-07-29T12:30:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-29T14:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2014-07-29T15:30:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-29T17:00:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2014-07-29T23:50:00Z",
     "end": "2014-07-31T01:07:00Z"
    },
    {
     "sta... (line 33, file "Code") [0.837 seconds total runtime]
```

Any idea why I'm getting an "Invalid JSON string" error?

Comment: It may be that the response is too long and failing to parse somewhere in the Apps Script internals. Can you try a smaller date range and see if that works?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with this key elements: `"<Calendar Id>"` and `"<Another Calendar Id>"`. Try to use sequence string instead and withoud `<` and `>` characters that usually have special meaning.

Comment: As I said, those are real calendar id's (without less-than/greater-than symbols) in the real version.  I removed them in the code sample and in the error message for privacy reasons.  Sorry I wasn't more clear.  ;-)